# Comparing sets that contain nan in python

Tags: python, set, nan

I'm trying to compare two sets in python that contain `nan` but struggling to do so because `{float('nan')} != {float('nan')}`.  For example:

```
s1 = {float('nan'), 1}
s2 = {float('nan'), 1, 2}

assert set.issubset(s1, s2)
```

And I get an assertion error.  How can I handle this?

Comment: you left bracket in s2???

Comment: @user1507844: Please clarify what "How can I handle this" means. What do you want to happen?

Comment: @user1507844 you got what i tried to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also write a simple function for this. Note that `float('nan') == float('nan')` is False for `nan`; to check if any element is nan, we just have to compare it with itself.

```
def is_subset(s1, s2):
    no_nan_set = lambda s: {x for x in s if x == x}
    s1_nan, s2_nan = no_nan_set(s1), no_nan_set(s2)
    if s1_nan != s1 and s2_nan != s2:
        return s1_nan.issubset(s2_nan)
    elif s1_nan == s1 and s2_nan == s2:
        return s1.issubset(s2)
    else:
        return False
```

You can simplify the `if-elif-else` block

```
def is_subset(s1, s2):
    no_nan_set = lambda s: {x for x in s if x == x}
    s1_nan, s2_nan = no_nan_set(s1), no_nan_set(s2)
    return (s1_nan != s1 and s2_nan != s2 and s1_nan.issubset(s2_nan)) \
        or (s1_nan == s1 and s2_nan == s2 and s1.issubset(s2))
```

Note that if either of your set has two or more `nan`s (because `float('nan') != float('nan')`), this will work correctly, and similarly it will work all right if the `id`s of the `nan`s are different. And lastly, this will work even if you don't have the `nan`s in one or both of your set.

Answer (score 3):

One approach: identity is tested before equality (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#not-in) in the docs, for example), so it'd work if you use the *same* `nan`:

```
>>> nan = float("nan")
>>> s1 = {nan, 1}
>>> s2 = {nan, 1, 2}
>>> set.issubset(s1, s2)
True
```

even though

```
>>> s1 = {float("nan"), 1}
>>> s2 = {float("nan"), 1, 2}
>>> set.issubset(s1, s2)
False
```

Working with `nan`s is awkward enough that I'd try to avoid putting them in sets and switch to a different canonical form.  But you could always just make sure it's the same one:

```
>>> def one_nan(x, nan=float("nan")):
...     return nan if math.isnan(x) else x
... 
>>> set.issubset(set(map(one_nan, s1)), set(map(one_nan, s2)))
True
```

or a thousand variants on the same.  (I sometimes use `x != x` as a shortcut for nan-detection but it's probably a good idea to be explicit here.)

Answer (score 2):

Create temporary sets with all `nan` values removed, and compare those instead. Afterwards, handle the `nan` comparison separately. For example, you could check if both of the original sets contain `nan`.

Even if you could perform the comparison for your sets without the assertion exception, `float('nan') == float('nan')` will return `False` so there is little value gained from this set comparison (it will invalidate the rest of the comparison). You can check this behavior by printing `set.issubset`.

```
s1 = frozenset({float('nan'), 1})
s2 = frozenset({float('nan'), 1, 2})
print frozenset.issubset(s1,s2)
```

which prints `False`.

Although [`set` is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), you may generate the temporary sets as follows:

```
s3 = set([value for value in s1 if not math.isnan(value)])
```

(repeat for each temporary set as needed)

Comment: How can I remove nan from a set once it is already in the set?

Comment: @user1507844: [`sets` are deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). However, if you're not able to use `set.remove` to accomplish this, you could easily generate new sets that do not contain `nan`, and use `set.issubset`. For example, `s3 = set([value for value in s1 if not math.isnan(value)])` will generate a new `set` from `s1` containing all values not equal to `nan`. I also edited this comment into my original post, in case the syntax here is confusing.

Comment: Creating a new set is probably easiest...just didn't know about math.isnan.  Thanks!